# Delete a certain percentage elements from a list while preserving the structural integrity of the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a value and an object, as shown below:

```
[(1, object0), (1, object1), (0, object2), (5, object3)]
```

Now were I to delete 25% of the tuples, with the lowest value within the first entry, within this list, I would be getting:

```
[(1, object0), (1, object1), (5, object3)]
```

Here the structural integrity of list is still intact while the elements have been deleted. I have explored options with a priority queue, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient method to do this. Please describe the time complexity of the solution.

I should elaborate that I am looking for the bottom 25% by value of the list from the previous example. If the list were to be sorted ascending, I would get:

```
[(0, object2), (1, object0), (1, object1), (5, object3)]
```

The lowest 25% now would be the first element, but when I output, I retain the structural integrity of the original list. The order of the result does not matter as long as it does not contain the bottom 25%, by value, of the original list.

### Possible Solution

A possible solution that I believe would work is using a min-priority queue that holds the tuples, and get added to it from a list. However, they also get added to a doubly linked list at the same time. When all the elements have been added to the queue and the doubly linked list, the first certain percentage of elements are popped from the queue and then deleted from the linked list. The linked list after all the deletes becomes the final answer.

Comment: what is the deletion rule? as example is showing you have removed middle element? If you want to delete from bottom, list.pop will always be done in constant time.

Comment: @Sach I modified the question - It explains the problem a bit better now.

Comment: I still don't get any solid idea what you want but elements of list in python are in persistent so you won't loose any structural integrity while removing any and it takes O(n) to remove an element.

Comment: @P.hunter Is there a way to remove the element from the immutable list without an O(n) remove charge? My possible solution take O(n) add and remove, while preserving structural integrity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls = [(1, 'object0'), (1, 'object1'), (0, 'object2'), (5, 'object3')]
p25 = m.ceil(len(ls)/4)
ls25 = []
res  = []
for i,j in ls:
    if len(ls25)<p25:
        ls25.append(i)
    elif i < max(ls25):
        ls25.remove(max(ls25))
        res.append((i,j))
        ls25.append(i)
    else:
        res.append((i,j))
print(res)




output
[(1, 'object1'), (1, 'object2'), (5, 'object3')]
```

Comment: Time  and space complexity both are  o(n)

Comment: @nBrail no it's not, min and max takes O(n), remove also takes O(n). So, it's O(n^2)

Comment: sry, thanks for reminding whats your expectation of TC.